# Getting the envelope of a family of curves.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When getting the envelope of a family of curves that represent the general solution of an ODE, why do we differentiate wrt c and equate to zero? I would like a simple proof or a good reference for this.

I mean for example, the ODE
$$y=2xy'+y^2y'^3$$
has a general solution 
$$y=2c\frac{x}{y}+\frac{c^3}{y}$$
If we differentiate the general solution w.r.t. $c$, we will get the singular solution which is the envelope of the general solution
$$y^4=-\frac{32}{27}x^3.$$

Comment: In your question, you introduces a symbol $c$ which comes like a  fly in the ointment. What is $c$ ?

Comment: @JJacquelin Sorry for that , I edited the post and added an example to clarify.. c is the constant in the general solution of an ODE

Comment: This is well explained in : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)

Answer (score 4):

Consider the diagram

[image]

where the point of intersection is a point near the evelope. The smaller $\mathrm{d}c$, the closer to the envelope we get.

This means that the point on the envelope is at the intersection of
$$
f(x,c)=0
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial c}f(x,c)=0
$$

---

**Example**

The family of lines parametrized by $a$:
$$
\frac{x}{1-a}+\frac{y}{a}=1
$$
Take the derivative with respect to $a$:
$$
\frac{x}{(1-a)^2}-\frac{y}{a^2}=0
$$
Solve simultaneously
$$
x=(1-a)^2\qquad y=a^2
$$
[image]

The family of lines is in black and the envelope is in  green. The envelope follows the intersection of adjacent curves.